# How to translate 撒娇?

Tags: translation, verbs, adjectives

In the context of:

```
你能向他撒娇。
```

**How would `撒娇` be translated?**

If `撒娇` is translated as flighty in the context of the sentence, it sounds a bit unnatural:

```
You can get flighty with him.
```

Comment: You can try 'flirt'.

Answer (score 2):

To understand 撒娇, you need to understand 撒尿。撒尿 means peeing or urinating。note, 撒 is the ing part of peeing. the word, 尿， is pee part of peeing. so the word 撒 simply means giving out something very comfortably and naturally, just like what you feel when you pee. for example,.仙女撒花，means goddess giving out flowers.

娇 means loveliness, or cuteness. so 撒娇 means giving out your cuteness to someone very comfortably and naturally. in short, it can be translated to English with a single word, flirting. but there is a twist. a little girl can 撒娇 her daddy. In that case, flirting is not correct. you should just use showing cuteness instead.

Answer (score 1):

[MDBG:撒娇](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E6%92%92%E5%A8%87)

the first two definitions:

> to act like a spoiled child
>
> to throw a tantrum

are the usual meanings of this word.

Think of a kid who has got a *boo-boo*, it doesn't really, super, hurt, but the child would love the attention of his mom and dad. So the kid puts on a show, cries and wails a little - the parents come running over to coax their kid. This is 撒娇.

perhaps something like: act a *sourpuss* / *whine*

你能向他撒娇。

- You can *whine* to him.
- You can be *pettish* with him.

or

- You can *garner* his attention.
- You can be *attention-seeking* with him.

Something like this.

---

edit: **sulkily**

Comment: why the down-vote?

Answer (score 0):

I discussed this with a native speaker. In the context of a girl 撒嬌 with her father, it can be described as showing cuteness, often in order to get something. There does not appear to be a direct translation to English.

Answer (score 0):

In my Chinese-English dictionary, it says 撒娇 means "coquetry", a kind of play cute, flirting, or toying around to arouse and gain the attention/interest of the other person.